# Setting Directory Locations

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
$dir = "Location: ../../../Wipe 2/Data";

// Run the recursive function 

$response = scan($dir);
```

So, what I am trying to do is create a global define for the directory location I want to use.  So, instead of typing ../../../Wipe 2/Data, I can put in a direct pathway (To make sure any file movements will not ruin my path)

My full path is

```
brandon/Wipe 2/Data
```

The path that the php file is in is

```
brandon/www/folders
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, why can't you set your dir to the one you want and that's it...?

Comment: why adding `Location:` ? does this work `$response = scandir('../../Wipe 2/Data/')` ? if not , do a `var_dump($response);` to see what directory you're in.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the full server path to your web documents with global `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

In your case, the directory you want is not in the document root.   So you can edit php.ini and edit `include_path` like this:

**Change**

```
include_path=".:/php/includes"
```

**To**

```
include_path=".:/php/includes:/brandon/Wipe 2/Data"
```

Be sure to restart httpd after making this change.

Comment: So, I think I found part of the issue.  The part of the directory that I want to access is outside of the 'www' folder, which may be causing the issue.

I got the Folder to appear as part of the directory, but it seems to show as empty because it is outside of the actual websites capabilities.  

is it possible to copy the data and have it update on the website as it updates in the original source location?

Comment: The neat thing about `include_path` is it can be set to any directory on the local server, so long as the apache user has read access to the full directory path(s) specified.

Comment: Alright, I'm fairly new with this stuff. But I do not have a php.ini file? Where is it/How do I make one/use it?

Thanks for all the help

Comment: The easiest way to find where your php.ini file is to create temporary .php script that only contains `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, upload that to your web server, then open it in a browser.  Near the top you'll see the path where your php.ini lives.   Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: I have looked everywhere, and did the above request, and I do not have a php.ini file ANYWHERE.  This webbase that I am using is literally bare minimums.  Is there another way?

Comment: What does your Loaded Configuration File setting show?  https://imgur.com/UDrEYU5   Also your php version and server OS.